# Call an asynchronous function with and without promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I have an asynchronous function that gives data on successful execution.
I have to make that asynchronous read call function in multiple places but in one of the function calls, I want to use it with promise as I have a dependency on the data retrieved.
How can I reuse the same function call with and without promise so as to reduce redundant code?

```
asyncFunc();   // returns "abcd"
doSomething(); // doesn't matter if we have the data "abcd" yet

asyncFunc().then(function (val){
doSomeOtherThing(val);
})
```

The "asyncFunc" is not returning any promise. I want to make use of it as a promise function.

Comment: please share `asyncFunc`

Answer (score 0):

Assign the promise to a constant on creation. Sth like

```
const promise = asyncFunc();   // returns "abcd"
doSomething(); // doesn't matter if we have the data "abcd" yet

promise.then(function (val){
doSomeOtherThing(val);
})
```

Comment: The asyncFunction does not actually return a promise. That's the issue with me

Comment: Why not using an optional parameter in the asynch function anf if set return your promise?